# How to empty array after it was initialized with the values from other array

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var arr1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
var arr2 = arr1;
arr1 = [];
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

when i make `arr1` empty, then `arr2`  is still not empty but has the values from `arr1`.
I want to make the length of arr2 to be zero.

I know that i can do

```
arr2 = [];
```

but is there any other way with which when we make changes to the `original` array - that to be reflected on the other arrays - which inherited their values ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
arr1 = [];
```

set the length to 0

```
arr1.length = 0;
```

or

```
arr1.splice(0, arr1.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

After you do `var arr2 = arr1`, the variables `arr2` and `arr1` both refer to the same array, but other than that, there is **no** link between them. When you do `arr1 = []`, you're changing the contents of `arr1` so it refers to a *different* array. The array that `arr2` refers to (and that `arr1` *used* to refer to) isn't in any way affected.

If you want to clear the array that both `arr1` and `arr2` refer to, you can do that by setting its `length` to `0` (since arrays are mutable):

```js
var arr1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
var arr2 = arr1;
arr1.length = 0; // <===
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

But let's be clear here: There's just **one** array in this scenario.

Let's look at this in more detail:

After the `var arr1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];` statement, you have something like this in memory:

```
                    +−−−−−−−−−−−+
arr1:Ref54132−−−−−−>|  (array)  |
                    +−−−−−−−−−−−+
                    | length: 6 |
                    | 0: "a"    |
                    | 1: "b"    |
                    | ...       |
                    +−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then when you do `var arr2 = arr1;`, you have:

```
                 
arr1:Ref54132−−−+
                |
                |
                |   +−−−−−−−−−−−+
                +−−>|  (array)  |
                |   +−−−−−−−−−−−+
                |   | length: 6 |
                |   | 0: "a"    |
arr2:Ref54132−−−+   | 1: "b"    |
                    | ...       |
                    +−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Note that the value of `arr1` and `arr2` are the same (a reference to the array, elsewhere in memory).

If you then do `arr1 = []`, you're changing `arr1` so it refers to a *different* array, one you just created with `[]`:

```
                    +−−−−−−−−−−−+
arr1:Ref64758−−−−−−>|  (array)  |
                    +−−−−−−−−−−−+
                    | length: 0 |
                    +−−−−−−−−−−−+

                    +−−−−−−−−−−−+
arr2:Ref54132−−−−−−>|  (array)  |
                    +−−−−−−−−−−−+
                    | length: 6 |
                    | 0: "a"    |
                    | 1: "b"    |
                    | ...       |
                    +−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

At that point, there's no connection at all between `arr1` and `arr2`.

But if you do `arr1.length` **instead**, you modify the state of the array `arr1` refers to (and `arr2` also refers to), removing all of its entries:

```
                 
arr1:Ref54132−−−+
                |
                |
                |   +−−−−−−−−−−−+
                +−−>|  (array)  |
                |   +−−−−−−−−−−−+
                |   | length: 0 |
                |   +−−−−−−−−−−−+
arr2:Ref54132−−−+
```